# How to identify/derive the pixel coordinate of vertices of an object in the render of a scene?

Tags: python

I am using version 2.93.6 of Blender and I am fairly new to Blender. I am struggling to find correct functions/APIs which would help me achieve the following:

From the example below we can see a scene and the viewport of the camera which shows what would get rendered to an image if one would like to do so. I would calculate programatically `X,Y` in pixel coordinates of the vertices of the cube. Is there a ready API or, collection of API functions which would enable me to do so?

Any guidance would be most welcome.

[image]

Comment: You might want to start [here](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/info_quickstart.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure certain what the right rule is for rounding camera coordinates to individual pixels, but I think examining coordinates in Camera space using `world_to_camera_view` and multiplying this by the Camera resolution in each of the `x, y` dimensions should be very close to what you want to do:

```
from bpy_extras.object_utils import world_to_camera_view
x_res = bpy.context.scene.render.resolution_x
y_res = bpy.context.scene.render.resolution_y
for i, v in enumerate(bpy.context.object.data.vertices):
    cam_coord_vec = world_to_camera_view(bpy.context.scene, bpy.data.objects['Camera'], bpy.context.object.matrix_world @ v.co)
    print(f"vertex # {i} has camera coordinates vector: {cam_coord_vec}")
    x_pixel = x_res * cam_coord_vec.x
    y_pixel = y_res * cam_coord_vec.y
    print(f"in pixels (unrounded): {x_pixel, y_pixel}")
    if 0.0 <= x_pixel <= x_res and 0.0 <= y_pixel <= y_res:
        print(f"in pixels (truncated): {int(x_pixel), int(y_pixel)}")
        print(f"in pixels (rounded): {round(x_pixel), round(y_pixel)}")
    else:
        print(f"Vertex lies outside of camera view.")
```

Example output on a new file with the Default Cube and standard default camera view of it:

```
vertex # 0 has camera coordinates vector: <Vector (0.6812, 0.7147, 10.7735)>
in pixels (unrounded): (1307.944107055664, 771.8815183639526)
in pixels (truncated): (1307, 771)
in pixels (rounded): (1308, 772)
vertex # 1 has camera coordinates vector: <Vector (0.6674, 0.3192, 11.6640)>
in pixels (unrounded): (1281.3787078857422, 344.7615337371826)
in pixels (truncated): (1281, 344)
in pixels (rounded): (1281, 345)
vertex # 2 has camera coordinates vector: <Vector (0.4928, 0.5843, 9.5452)>
in pixels (unrounded): (946.1326217651367, 631.0685062408447)
in pixels (truncated): (946, 631)
in pixels (rounded): (946, 631)
vertex # 3 has camera coordinates vector: <Vector (0.4934, 0.1534, 10.4357)>
in pixels (unrounded): (947.3159980773926, 165.6905597448349)
in pixels (truncated): (947, 165)
in pixels (rounded): (947, 166)
vertex # 4 has camera coordinates vector: <Vector (0.5039, 0.8240, 12.0766)>
in pixels (unrounded): (967.4798583984375, 889.9529600143433)
in pixels (truncated): (967, 889)
in pixels (rounded): (967, 890)
vertex # 5 has camera coordinates vector: <Vector (0.5036, 0.4608, 12.9672)>
in pixels (unrounded): (966.9661331176758, 497.6470613479614)
in pixels (truncated): (966, 497)
in pixels (rounded): (967, 498)
vertex # 6 has camera coordinates vector: <Vector (0.3180, 0.7217, 10.8483)>
in pixels (unrounded): (610.5794334411621, 779.4238471984863)
in pixels (truncated): (610, 779)
in pixels (rounded): (611, 779)
vertex # 7 has camera coordinates vector: <Vector (0.3318, 0.3282, 11.7388)>
in pixels (unrounded): (637.0874977111816, 354.452440738678)
in pixels (truncated): (637, 354)
in pixels (rounded): (637, 354)
```

And, when zooming in so that exactly 1 individual vertex is in the camera view:

```
vertex # 0 has camera coordinates vector: <Vector (1.6310, 1.8400, 1.7263)>
in pixels (unrounded): (3131.4981079101562, 1987.1581935882568)
Vertex lies outside of camera view.
vertex # 1 has camera coordinates vector: <Vector (1.2461, -0.3058, 2.6168)>
in pixels (unrounded): (2392.500686645508, -330.248122215271)
Vertex lies outside of camera view.
vertex # 2 has camera coordinates vector: <Vector (0.3615, 2.1165, 0.4979)>
in pixels (unrounded): (694.1628456115723, 2285.783586502075)
Vertex lies outside of camera view.
vertex # 3 has camera coordinates vector: <Vector (0.4503, -2.1049, 1.3885)>
in pixels (unrounded): (864.6673393249512, -2273.3101558685303)
Vertex lies outside of camera view.
vertex # 4 has camera coordinates vector: <Vector (0.5155, 1.7917, 3.0294)>
in pixels (unrounded): (989.8183822631836, 1935.0868606567383)
Vertex lies outside of camera view.
vertex # 5 has camera coordinates vector: <Vector (0.5120, 0.3703, 3.9199)>
in pixels (unrounded): (983.0441665649414, 399.89579916000366)
in pixels (truncated): (983, 399)
in pixels (rounded): (983, 400)
vertex # 6 has camera coordinates vector: <Vector (-0.5962, 1.8353, 1.8010)>
in pixels (unrounded): (-1144.6806335449219, 1982.1323347091675)
Vertex lies outside of camera view.
vertex # 7 has camera coordinates vector: <Vector (-0.2335, -0.2493, 2.6916)>
in pixels (unrounded): (-448.320837020874, -269.2303079366684)
Vertex lies outside of camera view.
```

Caveats:

- as written, this code ignores shape keys (these change the way you need to compute the vertex's position in world space, before passing it to `world_to_camera_view`)
- this does the computation for the currently active object and an assumed-to-exist camera named "Camera" (swap out `bpy.context.object` for some other object reference if you want to do it on a different object, and swap out `bpy.data.objects['Camera']` if you want to compute with a different camera)
- I wrote and tested this in `2.83.2`, not `2.93.6`
- I wrote/tested this in the Python REPL embedded inside the `Scripting` tab of a new Blender file, where Blender already pre-imports the `bpy` library. You'll need to explicitly import this if you're using this in code for an `Add On` you're writing or some such
- As I said initially, if it is important that you not just be very close to the right pixel (which this will achieve), but get the *exact* pixel value, then you'll need to figure out the proper rounding rule. Probably the simplest way to do this is to generate a few test renders and open them in software that lets you browse the image on a per-pixel level (e.g., PS or GIMP I think could do this), and to try a few different rounding rules until you find one that seems to consistently work correctly

Comment: Thanks a lot for the code and tips to the APIs: `world_to_camera_view` as well as `matrix_world` in the `extras` module. I was not aware of those. I also notice that the above code need to be adjusted a bit because the rendered coordinates is "upside-down". For instance pixel (0,0) in a rendered image would be top-left while in `world_to_camera_view` it is bottom left. (i also note it is mentioned in the documentation). Thanks again !

Comment: Oh, yes, that's right; I forgot that people usually represent pixel-space with the origin in the top-left, and you're completely right that `world_to_camera_view` expresses in terms of a basis that places the origin in the bot-left. I'll amend the answer slightly later to note this, so new readers won't have to look in the comments